# $f$ Open, Closed and continuous but not a local homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, open-map, closed-map

Give an example of topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ and a map $f: X \to Y$ that
$f$ is an open, closed, and continuous but not a local homeomorphism.
(The map and the topological spaces have to satisfy these 4 characteristics simultaneously)

Comment: HINT: There is a simple example with $X=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $Y=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: [0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1]$, all in the usual topology, be given by $f(x,y)=x$ (the projection).

$f$ is open and continuous, as all projections are.

$f$ is closed as the domain is compact and the codomain is Hausdorff.

$f$ is not a local homeomorphism for dimension reasons, basically. Or: all open sets in the domain cannot be disconnected by removing a point, while (basic) open sets in the codomain can be, so they can never be homeomorphic.